# Determining NETWORKDAYS based on Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel

**Summary**
Sheet 1 - Includes PTO data for every person on a team.  This sheet gives me the person's name, the start and end date of their PTO for the year.

Ex:

```
    Sheet1
    --------Col1----------------Col2----------------Col3
    Row1    John                06/01/2017          06/10/17
    Row2    John                06/25/2017          07/05/17
    Row3    Jane                06/25/2017          07/05/17
    Row2    Robb                06/11/2017          06/15/17
```

Sheet 2 - Is projecting PTO per Resource Per Month. The Sheet includes a Cell that has the Start Date of the Projection Report and the End Date of the Projection Report.  It also includes every team member on the sheet.  So think...

```
    Sheet2
    A1 = "06/01/2017"
    A2 = "06/31/2017"
    A5 = "Name of Person"        
    A6 = "John"
    A7 = "Jane"
    A8 = "Robb"
    B5 = "# of PTO Days for Reporting Period"
```

On this sheet, Column 2 (B6:B8) I am trying to grab the total network days of each person's PTO based on the date range between A1 and A2.  So, those taking PTO that spills into the next month, I wouldn't want to grab TOTAL Network Days for that person, I'd only want to grab Network Days that fall into the range of A1 and A2.

Example - John has two PTO ranges.  One whose range is 06/01 - 06/10 (which falls into the range of A1 and A2), but another whose range is 6/25 - 7/05 (so, the 7/1 - 7/5 does NOT fall in the range of A1 and A2).  The later, I'd only want to record the NETWORKDAYS within June.

I've tried a few different formulas that enables me to read the name of the employee and only pull network days that fall in the range of A1 and A2, but I'm having difficulty find something that works.

Anyone know how I could have B6:B8 give me the data related to the Resource Name and try to grab all appropriate networkdays for June in Sheet1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need one helper column to extract the networkdays,

`Column D` is your helper column which finds the networkdays based on the range provided in `Sheet2`. Use the below formula in `column D (sheet1)` and drag down,

```
=IF(AND(B1>=Sheet2!$A$1,C1<=Sheet2!$A$2),NETWORKDAYS(B1,C1),IF(AND(B1<Sheet2!$A$1,C1<=Sheet2!$A$2,C1>=Sheet2!$A$1),NETWORKDAYS(Sheet2!$A$1,C1),IF(AND(B1>=Sheet2!$A$1,B1<=Sheet2!$A$2,C1>Sheet2!$A$2),NETWORKDAYS(B1,Sheet2!$A$2),0)))
```

[image]

Now you will have networkdays for each entry in `sheet1`, need to use a `SUMIF` to total it for each person in sheet2. Use the formula in `Sheet2 B6` and drag down,

`=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,A6,Sheet1!D:D)`

[image]

Hope this helps.

Note:- `NETWORKDAYS` ignores the weekends.

Comment: Using your example: cell-by-cell, it seems to work under the conditions you've set.  However, if I change the reporting month to July (07/01 - 07/31), the totals for "John" and "Robb" were displaying negative numbers.  This becomes an issue because, in the case of "John".  John, who is taking PTO twice in June, but one of his PTO ranges ends in July - I need a calculation that gives me the total of "3".  However, given your current excel formulas - I am returned -12.  Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: @GreatMUSA Thanks for catching it. I have updated my formula. Please try it now

Comment: @GreatMUSA Thats nice to hear